# Is there an equivalent to Octave's "lookfor" command in Julia?

Tags: octave, julia

How to seek a concrete function in Julia? `lookfor` would make it in Matlab / GNU Octave, how can it be done here?

Comment: MATLAB’s `lookfor` was great in the times before Google and online documentation. It is totally obsolete now. Online documentation allows for much better search and discovery. Use it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent of `lookfor` is `apropos`:

```
julia> apropos("fourier transform")
Base.DFT.fft

julia> apropos("concatenate")
Base.:*
Base.hcat
Base.cat
Base.flatten
Base.mapslices
Base.vcat
Base.hvcat
Base.SparseArrays.blkdiag
Core.@doc
```

Other useful functions, depending on what you're looking for, include `methodswith`, which can give you a list of methods that are specified for a particular argument type:

```
julia> methodswith(Regex)
25-element Array{Method,1}:
 ==(a::Regex, b::Regex) at regex.jl:370                                                                
 apropos(io::IO, needle::Regex) at docs/utils.jl:397                                                   
 eachmatch(re::Regex, str::AbstractString) at regex.jl:365                                             
 eachmatch(re::Regex, str::AbstractString, ovr::Bool) at regex.jl:362                                  
 ...
```

Comment: @ nightcod3r: note that `apropos`, like `lookfor` will not detect functions from packages that haven't been loaded. So it might be useful to google regardless: a nice way of going straight to official documentation / package pages is searching for `fourier transform site:julialang.org`

Comment: you're right @TasosPapastylianou, in the end it's all about googling.

Answer (score 0):

A comment on Fengyang's great answer. Notice the difference between searching at the Julia prompt with `apropos("first")` vs typing a question mark and the word `?first`.

As you type the question mark, the prompt changes to a question mark. If you type `"first"`, this is equivalent to the above (with less typing). If you type `first` *without* quote-marks, you get a search over the variables that are exported by the modules currently loaded.

Illustration:

```
help?>"first"
Base.ExponentialBackOff
Base.moduleroot
...  # rest of the output removed


help?>first 
search: first firstindex popfirst! pushfirst! uppercasefirst lowercasefirst

  first(coll)

  Get the first element of an iterable collection. Return the start point of
  an AbstractRange even if it is empty.
  ...  # rest of the output removed
```

If you search for a string, case is ignored. If you want to search within the `DataFrames` module, type `using DataFrames` before searching.

Comment: See also my question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527985/julias-equivalent-to-rs-double-question-mark-help-search/