# Julia's equivalent to R's ?? (double question-mark help.search across all packages)

Tags: julia

In `R` you can [search the documentation](https://www.r-project.org/help.html) by typing a question mark `?` or a double question mark `??`. **How do you search the manual for strings in the Julia REPL?**

```
>?first
No documentation for ‘first’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??first’

>??first
```

In the `R` console a browser window opens up:

[image]

In `RStudio` the page is opened within the IDE.

> The help() function and ? help operator in R provide access to the
> documentation pages for R functions, data sets, and other objects,
> both for packages in the standard R distribution and for contributed
> packages.

The help() function and ? operator are useful only if you already know the name of the function that you wish to use. Other ways to search include `apropos` and `??`

> The apropos() function searches for objects, including functions,
> directly accessible in the current R session that have names that
> include a specified character string.

> The ?? operator is a synonym for help.search(). The help.search()
> function scans the documentation for packages installed in your
> library. The argument to help.search() is a character string or regular expression.

P.S. I intend to answer my own question.

Comment: Does R's `??` search _all_ packages in CRAN or just the loaded ones?

Comment: @mbauman It seems `?` searches for _loaded_ packages, while `??` searches for _installed_ packages: "The help.search() function scans the documentation for packages installed in your library." and "The ?? operator is a synonym for help.search()" (from the OP link) Any case, not from the whole CRAN...

Comment: Thanks for these clarifications. I really only ever used `?` and `??` and never noticed the difference between `loaded` and `installed`, but that's actually a very important one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julia has similar [interactive utilties](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/). Julia's main search utility for docstrings is named `apropos`.

To search the documentation for information about "first" in Julia, you have `apropos("first")` or equivalently `?"first"`. Thus `?"first"` is roughly equivalent to `R`'s `??`.

To search for functions and methods, you can type a singe question mark `?`, just as with `R`. In the Julia REPL, as you type the question mark, the prompt changes to a question mark. If you type `"first"` it searches through strings, while if you type `first` *without* quote-marks, you get a search over variables exported by the modules currently loaded.

Illustration:

```
help?>"first"  

# or equivalently:

julia>apropos("first")
```

[image]

```
help?>first
```

[image]

If you search for a string, case is ignored. If you want to search within the `DataFrames` module, type `using DataFrames` before searching.

This also works in `Visual Studio Code` and `Atom`:

[image]

Comment: I thought `appropos` just lists all the functions which has the word `first` in them. That's both in `Julia` and `R`.(Note that there is `appropos` in both R and Julia). I perceive OP is asking with regards to help page.

Comment: Well, `apropos` in Julia corresponds to `apropos` in R. so still I do not see how this fits the answer to `??` for Julia

Comment: There is also `??` in Julia, BTW. It's for "Extended help" which, in some docstrings, is more examples etc.

Comment: @mcabbott, I didn't know that. How do you use `??` in Julia? And where is the documentation? Feel free to post an answer! Thanks.

Comment: Extended help was introduced in Julia 1.5.  Do it like this: `help?> ?first` (the first question mark moves you to the help prompt, the second one is a literal prefix on the name).

Comment: Thanks @mbauman, Well for me `?` followed by `first` gives the same result as `?` followed by `?first`, so I couldn't tell there was a difference. Also it's not a string search like `??` does in `R`, am I understanding correctly?